# Check if a folder has a certain type of file present

Tags: shell, files, wildcards

How could I check if a file has a file of extension .java?

So far I have:

```
  for javaFile in *.java ; do
    {
        echo "The file $javaFile has : " >> ~/Desktop/externalServers.txt
        grep -E '^[^/]{2}.*http' $javaFile >> ~/Desktop/externalServers.txt     

        grep -E '^[^/]{2}.*ftp' $javaFile  >> ~/Desktop/externalServers.txt

        echo "----------------------------------------" >> ~/Desktop/externalServers.txt
        sed -e "s/[[:space:]]\+/ /g" ~/Desktop/externalServers.txt >> ~/Desktop/externalServersTemp.txt
        rm ~/Desktop/externalServers.txt
        mv ~/Desktop/externalServersTemp.txt ~/Desktop/externalServers.txt
        sed 's/^\n//' ~/Desktop/externalServers.txt >> ~/Desktop/externalServersTemp.txt
        rm ~/Desktop/externalServers.txt
        mv ~/Desktop/externalServersTemp.txt ~/Desktop/externalServers.txt

    } done
```

But every time I do that, I get the error:

> grep: *.java: No such file or directory

Basically I want to first see if the folder has any files of type .java and only continue with the script.

Comment: That's a useless use of `ls ..` you have there. Let the shell expand the arguments for you as Joseph's answer shows.

Comment: @slm - Joseph's answer demonstrate how *a* shell can expand the arguments in a way that is neither more readable nor more concise than my answer does for *any* shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Bash, simply use

```
shopt -s nullglob
for pdfFile in *.java;do
    # your code goes here
done
```

This syntax is for Bourne-like shells; the `nullglob` option is specific to bash. The braces you used (`{}`) are for C-style shells.

`shopt -s nullglob` sets the `nullglob` option, which basically tells Bash that globs that failed to match should be expanded into the null string. By default, if `*.java` fails to match, it is expanded into itself (the asterisk stays).

Comment: I just prefer to have the ( {} ) because it helps me differentiate the loops.. :/

Comment: @Unknown Well, if you're using Bash, you can't. It's syntactically incorrect.

Comment: ugh okay will change it :( . . . Could you check the new edited question?

Comment: @Unknown Please see the update.

Comment: what does shopt -s nullglob do??

Comment: @Unknown It sets the `nullglob` option, which basically tells Bash that globs that failed to match should be expanded into the null string. By default, if `*.java` fails to match it is expanded into `*.java` (i.e. with a literal asterisk).

Comment: @Unknown - please see my answer for methods explaining how to handle all of these things - including the `{` curlies `}` in `bash` - portably and simply without having to set any shell-specific and persistent shell options.

Answer (score 4):

My own rendition of your script would probably look like:

```
set -- *.java
test -e "$1" && {
    fortyequals=$(printf '%040d\n' | tr 0 \=)
    for javaFile do
        printf '%s\nIn file: %s\n%s\n' \
            $fortyequals "$javaFile" $fortyequals
        grep -E '^[^/]{2}.*(ftp|http)' "$javaFile"       
    done 
} >>~/Desktop/externalservers.txt
```

The solution already offered is *needlessly* shell-specific. You could achieve the same effect with portable syntax - which makes for less to remember in the long run with the added advantage of being more robust like:

```
set -- *.java
test -e "$1" &&
    for javaFile do
#       ...iterate on $javaFile here...
    done
```

Another advantage is that you not only retain the most recent value of `$javaFile` following the loop, you also retain *all* of the values that `$javaFile` ever had in `$@`. This makes the following possible:

```
...
done

echo "The previous for loop processed $# files."

echo "The first file processed was:"
printf "///\t'%s'\t///\n" "$1"

echo "The last file processed was:"
printf "///\t'%s'\t///\n" "$javaFile"

echo 'All files processed in the for loop were:'
printf "///\t'%s'\t///\n" "$@"
```

And if you do really like the `{` curlies `}` you can use them - even in `bash` *(though they are unnecessary)* - but you have to delimit between the two shell *reserved words* `}` and `done` like:

```
for ... do {
...
} ; done
```

Though my recommendation is that you enclose the entire block - *around* the `for` loop and any post processing you do - in curlies dependent on the `&&` *reserved words* like:

```
set -- *.java
test -e "$1" && {
    for ... done
#   ...further processing on $@...
}
```

Looking back at it and I believe I can help a great deal with the regex as well... It looks like we're looking for lines containing the words *http* and/or *ftp* that do *not* begin with two *//*.

I think the rest is a result of the separate `grep` operations you do. You appear to be attempting to clear blank lines, but, as I imagine, those are only caused in the first place by repeated appended writes to the file.

So, instead, we could just write `for` loop's output directly to the outfile in order to maintain the write descriptor for `~/Desktop/externalservers.txt` until the loop has finished, which should avoid any blank lines being written. Maybe like:

```
for ... done >>outfile
```

Or

```
{ grouped ; command ; list ; } >>outfile
```

At the very least I can tell you that this statement probably does not do what you want:

```
sed 's/^\n//' $file
```

`sed` is `\n`ewline delimited - it's impossible to encounter a `\n`ewline as the `^`first character on a line. You can get `\n`ewlines into `sed`'s pattern space by various means, but never without some processing.

Answer (score 2):

Another issue with the sample code, you generally want to [use double quotes on any of the iterators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) as you use them within the for loop.

Your code:

```
for javaFile in *.java ;
    {
        echo "The file $javaFile has : " >> ~/Desktop/externalServers.txt
        grep -E '^[^/]{2}.*http' $javaFile >> ~/Desktop/externalServers.txt     

        grep -E '^[^/]{2}.*ftp' $javaFile  >> ~/Desktop/externalServers.txt
```

Should be:

```
for javaFile in *.java ; do
        echo "The file $javaFile has : " >> ~/Desktop/externalServers.txt
        grep -E '^[^/]{2}.*http' "$javaFile" >> ~/Desktop/externalServers.txt

        grep -E '^[^/]{2}.*ftp' "$javaFile"  >> ~/Desktop/externalServers.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Joseph's `nullglob` approach is the most elegant but if you don't want to or can't use that (non-bash shell or older bash version for example), you can also do this (assuming your file names contain no newlines):

```
file="~/Desktop/externalServers.txt"
while IFS= read -r javaFile
do
  echo "The file $javaFile has : " >> "$file"
  grep -E '^[^/]{2}.*http' "$javaFile" >> "$file"
  grep -E '^[^/]{2}.*ftp' "$javaFile"  >> "$file"

  echo "----------------------------------------" >> "$file"
  ## The -i flag enables in-place editing so you don't need
  ## to fiddle about with temp files.
  sed -i -e "s/[[:space:]]\+/ /g" "$file"
  sed -i -n '/[^[:space:]]/p' "$file"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.java')
```

The `IFS=` sets the input field separator to empty so that you can deal with filenames that contain spaces correctly and the `-r` option to `read` means that backslashes are not treated specially (in case your filenames can contain them). The `<(command)` construct is called [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) and is a way of passing the output of one command as input to another.

I introduced the variable `$file` so that you don't need to edit every line if you ever want to change the output file name.

Note that I used the `-i` flag to sed which allows you to edit the original file and removes the need for temp files. Also note that there is no reason to do `rm foo.txt; mv bar.txt foo.txt`, you can always just do `mv bar.txt foo.txt` and that will overwrite the target file. Now, I have no idea what this command was supposed to do:

```
sed 's/^\n//' ~/Desktop/externalServers.txt >> ~/Desktop/externalServersTemp.txt
```

I am guessing that you want it to remove blank lines but that won't work so I changed it in the above with

```
sed -i -n '/[^[:space:]]/p' ~/Desktop/externalServers.txt
```

The `-n` suppresses sed's default  behavior of printing each line, the `/[^[:space:]]/` will match any lines that match any non-space character and the `p` at the end means that these lines and only these lines will be printed. If this is not what you wanted to do with your `sed` command, let me know and I will edit as needed.

Comment: Process substitution only exists in bash, ksh and zsh anyway. You could use a pipe instead, with the caveat that in shells other than ATT ksh and zsh, the right-hand side of the pipeline runs in a subshell. `-maxdepth` is specific to GNU and BSD find. Running `find` for this is overkill and chokes on file names containing newlines. There are more reliable ways to do this, and simpler if you don't need cross-shell portability.

Comment: @Gilles - simpler still, *and including* cross-shell portability would be the use of `set`.

Comment: @terdon - I added an answer demonstrating how I think this should be best handled portably. If you `set -- $glob ; test -e "$1"` you can know if the `$glob` expanded without any unnecessary shell options.